# string linear search c#

Tags: c#, search, text-files

I am currently doing a small C# exercise that deals with searching related terms/words in an text file and the program will write out all sentences in the text file that include the searched word. For instance, I enter the word: "example", and what the program will do is go through all the sentences in a text file and pull out those sentences that have the word "example" in them.

```
The text file is structured as so: <sentenceDesignator> <text>
sentence 1: bla bla bla bla example of a sentence  //each line contains a sentence
sentence 2: this is not a good example of grammar
sentence 3: bla is not a real word, use better terms
```

What I would like to be able to do is use a linear search to go through all the lines in the text file and write out all sentences that contain the searched string term.

My code so far:

```
        String filename = @"sentences.txt";

        if (!File.Exists(filename))
        {
            // Since we just created the file, this shouldn't happen.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} not found", filename);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully found {0}.", filename);
        }
        //making a listof type "Sentence" to hold all the sentences
        List<Sentence> sentences = new List<Sentence>();

        //the next lines of code...
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);

        //first, write out all of the sentences in the text file

        //read a line(sentence) from a line in the text file
        string line = reader.ReadLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            Sentence s = new Sentence();

            //we need something to split data...
            string[] lineArray = line.Split(':');

            s.sentenceDesignator = lineArray[0];
            s.Text = lineArray[1];

            Console.Write("\n{0}", line);

            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }

        //so far, we can write out all of the sentences in the text file. 
        Console.Write("\n\nOK!, search a term to diplay all their occurences: ");
        string searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();

       if(!line.Contains(searchterm))
       {
          Console.Write("\nThat term does not exist in any sentence.");
       }
       else
        {
            foreach (Sentence ss in sentences)
            {
                if (ss.sentenceDesignator.Contains(queryName))
                {
                    //I need help here
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot faster if you constructed an index of the file and then searched the index, as with a linear search every search operation is `O(n)` whereas with an indexed search it's `O(n)` for constructing the index, but `O(log n)` or `near-O(1)` for lookup (depending on how you build your index). The cost is increased memory consumption for the index, but I'd do it like this:

```
private Dictionary<String,List<Int32>> _index = new Dictionary<String,List<Int32>>();

/// <summary>Populates an index of words in a text file. Takes O(n) where n is the size of the input text file.</summary>
public void BuildIndex(String fileName) {

    using(Stream inputTextFile = OpenFile(...)) {

        int currentPosition = 0;
        foreach(String word in GetWords(inputTextFile)) {

            word = word.ToUpperInvariant();
            if( !_index.ContainsKey( word ) ) _index.Add( word, new List<Int32>() );
            _index[word].Add( currentPosition );

            currentPosition = inputTextFile.Position;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>Searches the text file (via its index) if the specified string (in its entirety) exists in the document. If so, it returns the position in the document where the string starts. Otherwise it returns -1. Lookup time is O(1) on the size of the input text file, and O(n) for the length of the query string.</summary>
public Int32 SearchIndex(String query) {

    String[] terms = query.Split(' ');

    Int32 startingPosition = -1;
    Int32 currentPosition = -1;
    Boolean first = true;
    foreach(String term in terms) {
        term = term.ToUpperInvariant();

        if( first ) {
            if( !_index.Contains( term ) ) return -1;
            startingPosition = _index[term][0];
        } else {

            if( !ContainsTerm( term, ++currentPosition ) ) return -1;
        }

        first = false;
    }

    return startingPosition;
}

/// <summary>Indicates if the specified term exists at the specified position.</summary>
private Boolean ContainsTerm(String term, Int32 expectedPosition) {

    if( !_index.ContainsKey(term) ) return false;
    List<Int32> positions = _index[term];
    foreach(Int32 pos in positions) {

        if( pos == expectedPosition ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The implementation of `OpenFile` and `GetWords` should be trivial. Note that `GetWords` uses `yield return` to build an `IEnumerable<String>` of whitespace-separated words in the file, as well as dealing with your custom file format.

Comment: I dont want to know the position of where the string is. I want to search for all instances of the searched term, and then write out all the sentences that include that term.

Comment: Modifying the algorithm to search for all instances is a problem left up to the reader :) I intentionally don't provide exact solutions in my answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about the last if/else. It seems like you are only comparing the very last line of the file to the searchterm. Also, where does "queryName" come from? And do you want do print out the whole sentence ("bla bla bla bla example of a sentence") or just "sentence 1"? Also, you check if the sentenceDesignator contains the queryName, I thought you want to check if the actual Text contains the searchterm.

Maybe this will help you:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);    
var sentences = new List<Sentence>(lines.Count());

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var lineArray = line.Split(':');
    sentences.Add(new Sentence { sentenceDesignator = lineArray[0], Text = lineArray[1]});
}

foreach (var sentence in sentences)
{
    if (sentence.Text.Contains(searchTerm))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sentence.sentenceDesignator);
        //Console.WriteLine(sentence.Text);
    }
}
```